# 21 is a losing opening move in Sylver Coinage. Why??

Tags: analysis

Sylver Coinage Question. Is it just a losing opening move because the next player will respond with the prime 7? Does it relate to Hutchin's Theory? help.

sylver coinage: Two players take turns naming positive integers, but an integer is off limits if it’s the sum of nonnegative multiples of integers that have already been named. Once 1 is named, everything is off limits (because any positive integer is a sum of 1s), so that ends the game; the player who is forced to name 1 is the loser.

Comment: https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/15859-s11/notes/sylver-coinage.pdf  Fairly elaborate. Suggest writing a program for possible games with choices that are not very large. Ah: named after Sylvester.